Single-producer single-consumer queue
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<atomic>
template<typename T, int N>
class queue{
    private:
        T arr[N];
        std::atomic<int> diff{1};
        int producer{0};
        int consumer{0};
        std::mutex mut;
        std::condition_variable cv;
    public:
        void push(const T& a){
            while(diff==N)
                std::this_thread::yield();
            arr[producer] = a;
            producer = (producer+1)%N;
            diff++;
        }
        T pop(){
            while(diff==0)
                std::this_thread::yield();
            consumer = (consumer+1)%N;
            diff--;
            return arr[(consumer - 1 + N)%N];
        }
};

Can you al review my code. My interview wanted more optimised code but i don't understand what more I could have done in this code. Can anyone tell what loop holes are there in this code and How I could have optimized it?

Hello and Welcome to Code Review! You have the same question posted on SO. Cross-posting is not recommended on Stack Exchange sites, please, see

Incorrect initialization
You initialize diff to 1, but that means you allow a pop() before anything has been push()ed. I think it should be initialized to zero instead.
Unused mutex and condition variable
You have member variables mut and cv that are never used. You should remove them.
push() can overwrite the value about to be pop()ed
There is a bug in pop(): you decrement diff before reading and returning a value from arr[]. That means a concurrent push() can overwrite that value between the diff-- and the return statement.
You must read from arr[] before decrementing diff. That will also make the code more efficient, as then you won't need to calculate (consumer - 1 + N) % N.
Use std::size_t instead of int
Use std::size_t consistently for sizes, counts and indices. It is guaranteed to be large enough to be able to address anything that can be stored in memory.
Prefer to move objects if possible
Your push() function copies a into arr[], and pop() also returns a copy of what is in arr[]. Making a copy might be inefficient, and might not even be possible if T is not a copyable type. To avoid this issue, add an overload to push() that takes an r-value reference:
void push(T&& a) {
    …
    arr[producer] = std::move(a);
    …
}

Also let pop() move the value from arr[]:
T pop() {
    …
    T value = std::move(arr[consumer]);
    …
    return value; // NRVO
}

To allow a queue of move-only types, you might have to use a requires clause to disable the version of push() that tries to make a copy.
Proper construction and destruction of queue elements
One issue your queue has is that it always creates N objects of type T, and then only copies/moves them. This has several issues:

It requires T to have a default constructor.
Side effects of the constructor and destructor of T are not called when expected.

For the latter, consider testing your queue with the following type:
struct Foo {
    Foo() { std::cerr << "Foo constructed\n"; }
    ~Foo() { std::cerr << "Foo destructed\n"; }
};

If you then write:
int main() {
    queue<Foo, 10>;
}

It will print that 10 Foo objects are constructed, and then afterwards destructed, even though nothing was push()ed into it.
This is unavoidable if you declare arr as T arr[N]. Ideally, you create enough space for N elements of type T (which must be properly aligned), and then manually construct and destruct elements into that space as you push() and pop(). This is made easier in C++20 with functions such as std::construct_at() and std::destroy_at(). However, this all requires a quite advanced understanding of C++.
An easier way to do this is to declare an array of std::optionals:
std:optional<T> arr[N];

This has a small overhead though, as now every element of arr[] tracks whether it contains a value or not.
Waiting for the other thread
Both push() and pop() might have to wait for the queue to not be completely full or not completely empty respectively. You do this by having a loop that calls std::this_thread::yield(). That may or may not be the most efficient way, depending on the number of CPU cores and the number of threads that are running. yield() is a system call that might cause the thread to be suspended for a long time, or it might immediately return, regardless of what the other thread in the single-producer, single-consumer program is doing. You will very likely wait either too short or too long.
There is no single best way to solve this issue. A widely used compromise is to not call yield() in the first few iterations of the while-loop, as this would allow another thread to increment/decrement diff without the first thread having to yield its timeslice.
Also, instead of yield()ing, you can consider using wait() to wait for the value of diff to change. While this will make waiting itself more optimal, it also requires the other thread to call notify_one(), which is a system call.
Using a std::mutex and a std::condition_variable is also not bad; if there is no lock contention then these will not cause any system calls to be made.
If you are in an interview, then it would help to know of the various tradeoffs you can make, and either ask the interviewer what to optimize for, or explain to them what the pros and cons of each of the alternatives are.

Thank you for your answer. butCan you kindly explain this statement:- Side effects of the constructor and destructor of T are not called when expected.
and can you please also help me with if there was any other optimal way to solve this problem. Because according to me I have tried to make it lock free and Tried to reduce the cycles of spin lock and tried to avoid unnecessary locking mutex. But interview said how can you optimize it more.
Can you kindly tell what should I have said him?? How could I have optimized it more in terms of logic?
